# Binding INADDR_ANY:<port> and INADDR6_ANY_INIT:<port> for listening fails on Linux but succeeds on macOS

Tags: sockets, networking, bind, listen

I'm writing a server application and I need it to listen for connections on all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for the host where it is running. The obvious thing to do is to listen on both INADDR_ANY and INADDR6_ANY_INIT. So I wrote my code accordingly but I am seeing strange behaviour.

On macOS (10.15.4 FWIW) things work just fine if I bind first to INADDR_ANY: and then subsequently (on a different socket of course) to INADDR6_ANY_INIT. If I reverse the order of the binds then the second bind fails with 'Address already in use'. The code binds just fine to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with the same port (different sockets of course) for any explicit address (i.e. not the wildcard address).

On Linux (I've tried a few flavours) the second bind always fails with 'Address already in use' regardless of the order thus it is impossible for my 'server' to work I the way I need it to. Of course it must be possible to do this since it is a common thing to do and many existing things do exactly this (sshd being just one example).

I have distilled the problem down into a functional example program but it is 434 lines long so probably too long to post here but anyone who is interested can download it from here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

static void
usage(
    void
     )
{
    printf(
    "\nUsage:\n\n"
    "    nwbug <port> [ <hostname> | <ipaddress> ]\n\n"
          );
    exit( 100 );
} // usage

/*
 * Print an IPv4 address.
 */

void
printIPv4address(
    FILE *f,
    struct sockaddr *addr4,
    int full
                )
{
    unsigned char * addr;
    int adbyte, port,  i;

    if (  (f != NULL) && (addr4 != NULL)  )
    {
        addr = (unsigned char *)&(addr4->sa_data[2]);
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            adbyte = (int)*addr++;
            fprintf( f, "%d.", adbyte );
        }
        adbyte = (int)*addr++;
        fprintf( f, "%d", adbyte );
        if (  full )
        {
            port = (int)ntohs( *((uint16_t *)&(addr4->sa_data[0])) );
            if (  port  )
                fprintf( f, ":%d", port );
        }
    }
} // printIPv4address

/*
 * Print an IPv6 address.
 */

void
printIPv6address(
    FILE *f,
    struct sockaddr *addr6,
    int full
                )
{
    int advalue, port = 0, i;
    int zrl = 0, zrlm = 0, zrls = -1, zrle = -1;
    unsigned char * addr;
    unsigned char * p;
    char colon[2];

    if (  (f != NULL) && (addr6 != NULL)  )
    {
        addr = (unsigned char *)&(addr6->sa_data[6]);
        p = addr + 15;
        if (  full )
            port = (int)ntohs( *((uint16_t *)&(addr6->sa_data[0])) );
        if (  port  )
            fprintf( f, "[" );
        for (i=7; i>=0; i--)
        {
            advalue = (int)*p--;
            advalue += (256 * (int)*p--);
            if (  advalue == 0  )
                zrl++;
            else
            {
                if (  zrl  )
                {
                    if (  (zrl > 1) && (zrl >= zrlm)  )
                    {
                        zrls = i + 1;
                        zrlm = zrl;
                    }
                    zrl = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (  zrl  )
        {
            if (  (zrl > 1) && (zrl >= zrlm)  )
            {
                zrls = i + 1;
                zrlm = zrl;
            }
            zrl = 0;
        }
        if (  zrlm  )
        {
            zrle = zrls + zrlm - 1;
            strcpy(colon,":");
        }
        for (i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            advalue = (256 * (int)*addr++);
            advalue += (int)*addr++;
            if ( ! zrlm )
                fprintf( f, "%x:", advalue );
            else
            if ( advalue || (i < zrls) || (i > zrle) )
                fprintf( f, "%x:", advalue );
            else
            {
                fprintf( f, "%s", colon );
                if ( i )
                    colon[0] = '\0';
            }
        }
        advalue = (256 * (int)*addr++);
        advalue += (int)*addr++;
        if ( ! zrlm )
            fprintf( f, "%x", advalue );
        else
        if ( advalue || (i < zrls) || (i > zrle) )
            fprintf( f, "%x", advalue );
        else
            fprintf( f, "%s", colon );
        if (  port  )
            fprintf( f, "]:%d", port );
    }
} // printIPv6address

/*
 * Print an IPv4 or an IPv6 address.
 */

void
printIPaddress(
    FILE *f,
    struct sockaddr *addr,
    socklen_t laddr,
    int full
              )
{
    if (  (f != NULL) && (addr != NULL)  )
        switch ( laddr  )
        {
            case sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ):
                printIPv4address( f, addr, full );
                break;
            case sizeof( struct sockaddr_in6 ):
                printIPv6address( f, addr, full );
                break;
            default:
                fprintf( f, "<invalid>" );
                break;
        }
} // printIPAddress

/*
 * Convert a hostname and/or a service name to a list of
 * address structures that can be used either for listen()
 * or connect().
 */

int
hostToAddr(
           char * hostname,
           char * servname,
           int    listen,
           struct addrinfo ** addr
          )
{
    struct addrinfo * haddr = NULL, * caddr = NULL, gaihints;
    int ret = -1;

    if (  ( addr == NULL)  || 
          ( ( hostname == NULL ) && ( servname == NULL) ) ||
          ( ( hostname == NULL ) && ! listen )  )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error: invalid parameters passed to hostToAddr()\n" );
        return ret;
    }

    *addr = NULL;

    memset( (void *)&gaihints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo) );
    gaihints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    gaihints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    gaihints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    if (  listen  )
        gaihints.ai_flags |= AI_PASSIVE;

    ret = getaddrinfo( hostname, servname, &gaihints, addr );
    if (  ret  )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error: getaddrinfo() returned %d\n", ret );
        return ret;
    }

    return ret;
} // hostToAddr

int
main(
    int    argc,
    char * argv[]
    )
{
    struct addrinfo * addr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo * taddr = NULL;
    char            * host = NULL;
    char            * port = NULL;
    int               naddr = 0;
    int               sind = 0;
    int               ret = 0;
    int             * sock = NULL;

    if (  (argc < 2) || (argc > 3)  )
        usage();
    port = argv[1];
    if (  argc > 2  )
        host = argv[2];

    if (  hostToAddr( host, port, 1, &addr )  )
        return( 1 );

    taddr = addr;
    while (  taddr != NULL  )
    {
        if (  taddr->ai_family == PF_INET  )
        {
            printf( "info: address %d is '", naddr );
            printIPaddress( stdout, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
            printf( "'\n" );
        }
        else
        if (  taddr->ai_family == PF_INET6  )
        {
            printf( "info: address %d is '", naddr );
            printIPaddress( stdout, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
            printf( "'\n" );
        }
        else
            printf( "warning: unexpected protocol family\n" );
        naddr += 1;
        taddr = taddr->ai_next;
    }

    sock = (int *)calloc( naddr, sizeof( int ) );
    if (  sock == NULL  )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "error: unable to allocate memory for socket array\n" );
        return 2;
    }

#if 1
    sind = 0;
    for ( taddr = addr; taddr != NULL; taddr = taddr->ai_next )
    {
        if (  taddr->ai_family == PF_INET6  )
        {
            printf( "info: binding '" );
            printIPaddress( stdout, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
            printf( "'\n" );

            errno = 0;
            sock[sind] = socket( taddr->ai_family, taddr->ai_socktype, taddr->ai_protocol );
            if (  sock[sind] < 0  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: socket() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 3;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  bind( sock[sind], taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: bind() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 4;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  listen( sock[sind], 5 )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: listen() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 5;
                continue;
            }
            sind++;
        }
    }
    for ( taddr = addr; taddr != NULL; taddr = taddr->ai_next )
    {
        if (  taddr->ai_family == PF_INET  )
        {
            printf( "info: binding '" );
            printIPaddress( stdout, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
            printf( "'\n" );

            errno = 0;
            sock[sind] = socket( taddr->ai_family, taddr->ai_socktype, taddr->ai_protocol );
            if (  sock[sind] < 0  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: socket() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 3;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  bind( sock[sind], taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: bind() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 4;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  listen( sock[sind], 5 )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: listen() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 5;
                continue;
            }
            sind++;
        }
    }
#else
    sind = 0;
    for ( taddr = addr; taddr != NULL; taddr = taddr->ai_next )
    {
        if (  taddr->ai_family == PF_INET  )
        {
            printf( "info: binding '" );
            printIPaddress( stdout, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
            printf( "'\n" );

            errno = 0;
            sock[sind] = socket( taddr->ai_family, taddr->ai_socktype, taddr->ai_protocol );
            if (  sock[sind] < 0  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: socket() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 3;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  bind( sock[sind], taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: bind() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 4;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  listen( sock[sind], 5 )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: listen() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 5;
                continue;
            }
            sind++;
        }
    }
    for ( taddr = addr; taddr != NULL; taddr = taddr->ai_next )
    {
        if (  taddr->ai_family == PF_INET6  )
        {
            printf( "info: binding '" );
            printIPaddress( stdout, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
            printf( "'\n" );

            errno = 0;
            sock[sind] = socket( taddr->ai_family, taddr->ai_socktype, taddr->ai_protocol );
            if (  sock[sind] < 0  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: socket() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 3;
                continue;
            }
            errno = 0;
            if (  bind( sock[sind], taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: bind() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 4;
                continue;
            }
            if (  listen( sock[sind], 5 )  )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "error: listen() failed for '" );
                printIPaddress( stderr, taddr->ai_addr, taddr->ai_addrlen, 1 );
                fprintf( stderr, "' - %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
                ret = 5;
                continue;
            }
            sind++;
        }
    }
#endif

    if (  ret == 0  )
        printf( "info: success\n" );

    sleep( 60 );

    return ret;
} // main
```

Any and all suggestions, insights, pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that in order for this to work as expected one needs the following additional code to set a specific IPv6 related option on the socket *before* the bind() call:

```
int one = 1;
...
setsockopt( ctxt->lsocks[sno], IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (void*) &one,     sizeof(one));
```

This was surprisingly hard to find, though once you know what to look for it is of course easy to find.